# OpenCV cvInRange() not Working With cvScalar()

Tags: c++, opencv, compiler-errors

I am attempting to use the function `cvInRange()` from the `OpenCV` library, however, when I use:

```
cvInRange(image, cvScalar(100, 0, 0), cvScalar(256, 0, 0), processedImage);
```

I get the following error:

```
cannot convert ‘CvScalar’ to ‘const CvArr* {aka const void*}’ for argument ‘2’ to ‘void cvInRange(const CvArr*, const CvArr*, const CvArr*, CvArr*)’
                 cvInRange(image, cvScalar(100, 0, 0), cvScalar(256, 0, 0), processedImage);
```

Is there a way to specify the minimum and maximum threshold values for `cvInRange()` as `CvArr`s to prevent this problem from occurring, or is there some other way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several versions of `cvInRange()`. The one you want is [`cvInRangeS()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=cvinranges#void%20cvInRangeS%28const%20CvArr%2a%20src,%20CvScalar%20lower,%20CvScalar%20upper,%20CvArr%2a%20dst%29), which takes `CvScalar` as the two threshold arguments. Replacing the call to `cvInRange()` with `cvInRangeS()` will fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed 1 number on your code.
I remember that cvScalar have 4 tuple, and must type every number.
Example if you user RGB code that have 3 tuple :

```
RGB = 123,123,123
```

in cvScalar you must type like this

```
cvScalar example = cvScalar(123,123,123,0);
```